# Run Raketask after capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rake-task

How is it possible to run a rake task after the deployment has been finished?

I tried the following:

```
namespace :add_records do
  desc "Run a task on a remote server."
    task :default do
  run("cd #{deploy_to}/current; /usr/bin/env bundle exec rake my_task_group:test_records RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
end
```

The task gets executed during the deployment but results in an error.
I know that the task must run right after and not during the deployment.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it after last step of deployment, in your deploy.rb:

```
after :last_task_in_deploy, :task_you_want_to_run
```

If it is sufficient that deployment is finished, and server does not need to be restarted, run after :publish

```
  after :publish, :task_you_want_to_run
```